# How to map an array which is inside another array in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, rxjs, react-router

I am new to react and I am having trouble finding a way to map an array within an array to display the username and id in the component. How can I achieve this? Is this a wrong approach?

```
[Array(4)]
        0: Array(4)
            0: {user: "testuser1", id: "2"}
            1: {user: "testuser2", id: "3"}
            2: {user: "testuser3", id: "4"}
            3: {user: "testuser4", id: "5"}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)? It will explain how to map your data to components, which you can then render.

Comment: Hi, I am able map normal arrays without any problem, but here I'm finding it difficult to get it work. `userinfo` is the state which holds this array. `userinfo.0` throws an error.

Comment: It is the same idea, you'll just need one map to map the contents of the outer array, and then another to map the contents of the inner array `arr.map(inner => inner.map(obj => <p key={obj.id}>{obj.user}</p>));`. To access an element in an array, you could use `userInfo[0]`, but it's unclear whether your (outer) array can have more than one nested array. Using two maps will take care of both cases (0 or more nested arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prehistoricbeast - try this:

```
  return(
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
         return (
           <div key={key}>
              <h1>{key}</h1>
              {data[key].map((dataItem) => {
                return (
                 <span key={dataItem.user}>{dataItem.id}</span>
                )
               })}
           </div>
         )
       })}
     </div>
   )
```